# How to get the total byte size of schemas & databases in Snowflake

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, size, database-schema

I love how the `SHOW TABLES` query return the rows and the bytes for each table listed, but unfortunately, that's not the case for the `SHOW SCHEMAS` query.

What's the best way to get the total byte size of a list of schemas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've managed to do this by querying `information_schema.tables`:

```sql
SELECT
  table_schema AS schema,
  SUM(bytes) AS bytes
FROM information_schema.tables
GROUP BY schema;
```

Note that this only works for the current database, as each database has its own `information_schema`. So this wouldn't work to get the size of a list of databases. However, it's possible to get the total size of each DB individually:

```sql
SELECT SUM(bytes) AS bytes
FROM [database_name].information_schema.tables;
```

A nice complement to this is to use a UDF to format the byte size nicely, like the `nicebytes` example [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html), resulting in `nicebytes(SUM(bytes)) AS bytes` in  the query.

---

***EDIT:*** Many of those queries can be unioned in order to get the results for multiple databases/schemas at once. They can also be made to run daily and store the result into another table, which provides a nice way to monitor the size of databases & schemas over time:

```sql
SELECT
  table_catalog AS database,
  table_schema AS schema,
  SUM(bytes) AS bytes
FROM database_1.information_schema.tables
GROUP BY database, schema
UNION ALL
SELECT
  table_catalog AS database,
  table_schema AS schema,
  SUM(bytes) AS bytes
FROM database_2.information_schema.tables
GROUP BY database, schema;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have accountadmin access or have been granted access to the [Account Usage Views](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views) you could try using TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS.

```
select 
TABLE_CATALOG,
TABLE_SCHEMA, 
nicebytes(sum(ACTIVE_BYTES)) ACTIVE_STORAGE, 
nicebytes(sum(TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES)) TIME_TRAVEL_STORAGE, 
nicebytes(sum(FAILSAFE_BYTES)) FAILSAFE_STORAGE
from SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS
where TABLE_DROPPED IS NULL
and SCHEMA_DROPPED IS NULL
and CATALOG_DROPPED IS NULL
group by 1,2
order by 1,2,3
```

This also leverages the [nicebytes UDF](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html#examples-using-describe-and-show-commands)

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I wanted to avoid using `ACCOUNTADMIN` (for security purposes), since this is a query we are using in an automated script. But I didn't know it was possible to grant access to the Account Usage Views for other roles!

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Check this out: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#enabling-account-usage-for-other-roles